# Как сделать калькулятор в JS?

Tags: javascript, калькулятор

Как сделать калькулятор на сайте, который бы умножал количество и стоимость и выдавал сумму в JS, т.е. без перезагрузки в самом сайте.

Comment: А в чем проблема? Делайте 2 input и результат в любое место. событие input его и обрабатывайте

Comment: Добавьте подробностей в вопрос. Числа вводит пользователь?

Comment: Да, пользователь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на коленках буквально, не вкладывая никакого смысла и не извращаясь

```js
let a = document.getElementById("a");
let b = document.getElementById("b");
let c = document.getElementById("c");

let calulate = function() { 
 c.value = (+a.value)*(+b.value);
}

a.addEventListener("change", calulate);
b.addEventListener("change", calulate);
```

```html
<div>
 <input id="a" type="input"></input>
 *
 <input id="b" type="input"></input>
 =
 <input id="c" type="input"></input>
</div>
```

Прочим просьба не холиварить, ответ написан как примитивная помощь.

Comment: Ну, а минус за что? Если есть комментарии к улучшению с удовольствием выслушаю и вполне возможно изменю ответ так что вас тоже он устраивал.

Comment: Подскажите, перекопировал себе на сайт, не работает. В первую часть добавил <script></script>. Все равно не работает. А здесь работает. Туплю где-то, но где?

Comment: Скрипт загрузите после разметки. Добавьте тег <script> перед закрывающимся body

Comment: <script>....</script></body> у вас не работал потому страница обрабатывается с верху в низ. На момент загрузки скрипта элементы ещё не создались в DOM

Comment: Информация выводится в <span, но мне нужно чтоб выводилось в <input , так как я потом по средством Ajax буду вносить эти данные в базу. Можно так сделать?

Comment: Сделал смотрите

Answer (score 0):

```js
let form = document.querySelector('#form')
let sum = document.querySelector('#sum')

form.addEventListener('submit', evt => {
  evt.preventDefault()
  sum.textContent = +form.quantity.value * +form.price.value
})
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <label for="quantity">quantity</label>
  <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" />
  <label for="price">price</label>
  <input type="text" id="price" name="price" />
  <button>count</button>
</form>

<p id="sum"></p>
```